# How to put an input value into the array multiple times and remember it?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, session, post

Is there any solution for this? Sorry if I didn't explain this good.

When I put some value in $_POST['name'] and submit form I want to put that value in array( $arr ) and when I put some diferent value second time in $_POST['name'] and submit form I want that value put in array ( $arr ) to. Now that array should have two element ( first value and second value from $_POST['name'] )

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = 1;

$arr =array();  
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && trim($_POST['name']) != '') {
    $arr[] = $_POST['name'];
}    
print_r($arr);    
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" value="" />
<input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I started session, chacked if is form submitted and if is an empty field.
I tried with hidden input with value of $token = rand(); adn it not worked.

This should be easy, but I have some trouble do fix it.Tnx!

Comment: What has `$token = rand()` got to do with the code you posted???

Comment: What exactly are you expecting that code to do?

Comment: include all relevant code with your question? Read ithttps://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried with S_SESSION['token'] = $_POST['hidden'], adn $_POST['hidden'] was diferent everytime you submit form or refresh page and to clear input field on refresh.

Comment: No, it is just this code. This is exercise.

Comment: Which value do you want to add multiple times to which array?

Comment: I want to populate this array($arr) with input values. First submit is $arr[0], next submit is $arr[1] ..., sorry about my English.
I wont to do it without database.

Comment: Is there any solution for this? Sorry if I didn't explain this good.

When I put some value in $_POST['name'] and submit form I want to put that value in array( $arr ) and when I put some diferent value second time in $_POST['name'] and submit form I want that value put in array ( $arr ) to. Now that array should have two element ( first value and second value from $_POST['name'] ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a stateless language and doesn't store variables from one page load to another. Each time you are submitting the form the `$arr` variable is destroyed from memory when the page has been processed.

If you want to keep information across page loads then you need to store it in the super global variable `$_SESSION` as a key value pair.

If you use the modified code below it will store the value typed into the name input when the form is posted in a two level multidimensional array that can be accessed using `$_SESSION['name']` and a numeric index.

```
<?php

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['name']) && !is_array($_SESSION['name']))
{
    $_SESSION['name'] = array();
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && trim($_POST['name']) != '') {
    $_SESSION['name'][] = $_POST['name'];
}    
print_r($_SESSION); 

?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" value="" />
<input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```